# Add a ModelChoiceSet to an inlineformset after it's generated

Tags: python, django

I have an inlineformset based off a very simple Model form.  I'd like a way to add a choiceset to one of the fields of the form, but I want to do it from the views.py file as the choiceset is generated dynamically.  Is this possible?  Python2.7, Django1.5

models.py

```
class RoleForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = ['role_type', 'user', 'item']
```

views.py

```
def new(request):
    ''' Create a new application '''
    user = request.user
    associatedRoleTypes = getAssociatedRoleTypes(Application) 
    #^^^this returns a queryset, and is what I want model_choices to be equal to
    RoleFormSetFactory = inlineformset_factory(Application, Role, can_delete=False, form=RoleForm)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        applicationForm = ApplicationForm(request.POST)
        if applicationForm.is_valid():
            new_application = applicationForm.save()
            roleInlineFormSet = RoleFormSetFactory(request.POST, instance = new_application)
            if roleInlineFormSet.is_valid():
                roleInlineFormSet.save()
            else:
                print roleInlineFormSet.errors
            return redirect(reverse('index'))
    else:

        applicationForm = ApplicationForm()
        roleInlineFormSet = RoleFormSetFactory()
    return render(request, 'who/editapp.html',
        {'roleInlineFormSet': roleInlineFormSet,
         'applicationForm': applicationForm
         })
```

Comment: Can you show the code (both the view and the model) in question?

Comment: Of course--edited.  I only didn't include it on the first go because I was asking more in general if it were possible as I couldn't find information on it anywhere.